# How can I change the color of the axis labels in a slate chart?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

I am trying to change the color of the axis labels in a bar chart in Slate but setting the color property does not seem to do anything.
[image: uncolored axis despite code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the ‘fill’ property instead of the color property.
[image]